# webdrivers sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) fails on chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I used to have chrome ver 39 and `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` in my scripts ( click on links) and it used to work perfectly.

But now, my browser updated to ver 41 and for some reason it doesn't work anymore.
If I just click on the link it works fine but the `sendkey` fails.

I can use `.click` but sometimes it fails for IE so the `sendkeys` was a good solution for all browsers.

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Did U use latest chromedriver version ???
Why not use IE fixes in code ???
sendKeys Enter is ususally not good choice.

Comment: hi, .click use to fail ( not all the times but happens  on IE)  and i found that the sendkeys solved that problem. Yes, I have last chromedriver , which is 2.13 if I'm not wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
if(driver.toString().contains("internet explorer"){
//code with Keys.ENTER
}else{
normal code
}
```

It might be chromedriver issue, still it should work somehow.